# How to merge lines every 3 rows in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Like this:

```
A
B
C

D
E
F

G
H
I
```

To this:

```
A     B     C

D     E     F

G     H     I
```

It's a 2500 rows file, so i wouldn't just ctrl+j it.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to access the Replace dialog, tick Regular expression, and enter the above expressions. Here it is in text:

**Find what:** `(.+)\r\n(.+)\r\n(.+)` 
**Replace with:** `\1\t\2\t\3\t` (the last `\t` is optional; you won't visually notice any difference if you remove it, unless you are expecting the line to end with a tab character)

Replace `\r\n` in the "Find what:" with:

- `\n` if you are editing a file with UNIX-style line endings (linefeed only)
- `\r\n` if you are editing a file with Windows-style line endings (carriage return followed by line feed; in this case, you don't need to modify the original regex)
- `\r` if you are editing a file with traditional Mac-style line endings (carriage return only)

You can find out which line ending you're using by examining the status bar at the bottom of the Notepad++ window. It will say "Dos\Windows", etc.

---

**If your file has inconsistent line endings** (which is a bad thing in general, but not impossible) and you want to replace all possible types of newlines in one go:

**Find what:** `(.+)(\r|\n)+(.+)(\r|\n)+(.+)` 
**Replace with:** `\1\t\3\t\5\t`

You can learn more about regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all linebreak, not preceeded or followed by another line break, with a tabulation.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `[^\r\n]\K\R(?!\R)`
- Replace with: `\t`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
[^\r\n]     : not a line break
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
\R          : any kind of line break
(?!\R)      : negative lookahead, make sure we don'thave a line break after
```

**Replacement:**

```
\t          : a tabulation
```

**Result for given example:**

```
A   B   C

D   E   F

G   H   I
```