# How to add something every x line

Tags: notepad++

How do I add

```
Keyboard : E : KeyDown
DELAY : 1300
Keyboard : E : KeyUp
DELAY : 200
```

to every X line in a text document?

Comment: You can simply do it with a programming language like C or Java.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what your file already contains and what you'd like it to be replaced with? This can probably be done using the find/replace regular expressions feature of Notepad++, but I'd have to get a clearer example (similar to the example [here](http://superuser.com/q/678046/144607)) to provide a solution.

Comment: FYI you can do it online as well http://textmechanic.com/text-tools/basic-text-tools/addremove-line-breaks/

Answer (score 39):

To insert a new line after every 9 rows, go to `Search` > `Replace` menu (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and do the following:

1. Find what:

   ```
   (.*\r?\n){9}\K
   ```
2. Replace:

   ```
   Your new line\n
   ```
3. Select radio button "Regular Expression"
4. Then press `Replace All`

You can test it at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oJ2yO4).

Comment: This worked for me. But don't forget to uncheck the [x] ". as linebreaks" checkbox for regular search.

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Note, if your new line has any special regex characters like `\ ` or `*`, you'll need to escape them with a backslash. `\\ ` or `\*`.

Comment: Apperently \K is a little bug for replacing.  In my case I needed to use capture groups similar to the other answer instead of using \K.

Comment: It works! just noticed that In version v7.9.1 32bit It works if "Search Mode" set to Regular Expression and unchecked ". matches new line"

Comment: This command seems to work on smaller files, but on some large files (~70,000 lines) it has caused data corruption and then a crash.

Comment: Works fine, thanks! In response to @MarkBarnes, the "data corruption" has nothing to do with the regex function per se, it's more of a clash between the expression you're using and your data structure.  I've used this in 3 different files with 40k to 230k lines without any data corruption. Of course, a system and/ or application slowdown is a different matter which is understandable and even expected, when handling such large files.

Answer (score 4):

> Still using search/replace, this worked better in my case:
>   selects [your example 9 lines] in one group (the inner '()' pair for each line followed by 'newline'), then the '{}' pair for the look-ahead line count to grab, and the outer '()' pair for the 9 lines retained as a group

((.*\n){9})

> Use the \1 variable to restore the same [9] line group, followed by [your sample line insert] and a newline

\1\nKeyboard : E : KeyDown DELAY : 1300 Keyboard : E : KeyUp DELAY : 200\n

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: Tweaked to match OP syntax

Answer (score 0):

I'm note sure if it works in Notepad++, but this is how I solved it with PSPads phReplace:

Search:

```
(.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n)
```

Replace:

```
$1New Line[Enter]
```

`[Enter]` stands for pressing the Enter-Button as phReplace does not allow `\r\n` in replace field.

Comment: How is this better than @psxls answer?

Comment: @Toto His answer did not work for me.

Comment: It is strictly the same but condensed