# Notepad++ replace .|every 5th line with .}

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

I got a text that ends on every single line with `.|`

And I need to replace the `.|` on every 5th line with `.}`

Comment: I don't think np++ is the right tool for the job. It is best done from a script which reads through the file while counting the lines and copying each line, apart from those with line numbers divisible by 5, when an edited copy is made. This is very easy in Unix, using `bash`, `line` and `sed`, so it's probably most easily done in Windows with ports of these.

Comment: See this: http://superuser.com/questions/680416/how-to-add-something-every-x-line

Comment: You can also do this quite easily with a macro in NP++

Comment: Tony, tried to comment on your answer but it was deleted before I finished.  You have two SU IDs, which complicates things like editing your own questions and answers or accumulating rep.  Flag a moderator to get your accounts merged.  You will the be able to edit your question with the additional information you tried to post as an answer.  In the meantime, login under this user name to access your own question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to Unix tools (including Cygwin), you can do this with `sed`:

```
sed '0~5s/\.|$/.}/'
```

as in

```
sed -i.bak '0~5s/\.|$/.}/' filename
```

This uses `sed`’s *first*~*step* address form,
which means “match every *step*’th line starting with line *first*.”

If the `|` is always preceded by a **`.`**, as you say,
then you can leave the dots out of the command:

```
sed '0~5s/|$/}/'
```

Comment: I hadn't got round to exploring some of `sed`'s more advanced features: very neat solution!