# Notepad++: Prefix every line; start every line automatically with

Tags: notepad++, prefix

I want to automatically start every new line in Notepad++ with a string, for example `0`. I don't want to "replace", I want to **prefix**. How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add something every x line](http://superuser.com/questions/680416/how-to-add-something-every-x-line)

Answer (score 1):

you can use the notepad++ python script, register a callback on the notification key ( SCINTILLANOTIFICATION.MODIFIED [help](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/enums.html#SCINTILLANOTIFICATION.MODIFIED) ), in the callback function: append the prefix text when a new line has been added

Python code:

```
from Npp import *


def prefixNewLine(args):
    prefix = "0: "
    if args['linesAdded'] == 1:
        editor.addText(prefix)

editor.callback(prefixNewLine, [SCINTILLANOTIFICATION.MODIFIED])
```