# How to merge lines every 10 rows in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

There is an answere about 3 rows here [How to merge lines every 3 rows in Notepad++?](https://superuser.com/questions/678046/how-to-merge-lines-every-3-rows-in-notepad)
But this method doesnt work for 10

I need to do this:

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
10,
11,
12,
13,
14,
15,
16,
17,
18,
19,
20,
...
```

To this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
...
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it work for 10? Obviously you need to add more of the same thing to the find and replace. Can you share what are the find and replace you tried?

Comment: Please post all necessary information here.  We should not have to click on alink to see what the question is about.

Comment: Find: `(?<!0,)\R` and replace with nothing.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^[^,]+,)\R((?1))\R((?1))\R((?1))\R((?1))\R((?1))\R((?1))\R((?1))\R((?1))\R((?1))`
- Replace with: `$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9${10}`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/jLQgff/1)

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]